# Different list view for different portal

Tags: permissions, list-view, experience-cloud

I have a requestion regarding to list view of Case object.

As our production Org can create 100 sites in Experience Cloud, our team decided to build two different sites for two different types of customer.

All the customers use "Customer Community Login" licenses but we created two profiles for different customer types.

However, we would like to show different list views in different portal. For example, a user accesses portal 1 can only see the case list view "A" and another user accesses portal 2 can only see the case list view "B" but not "A". Is there possibility to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's not possible to restrict list views for that type of license.